# Open graph story in Swift get a all white screen

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharing

I am trying to post a graph story to Facebook. I have an app in which my users can track rides on bikes on different tracks. However this code just opens a plain white safari page and nothings else happens.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
   var properties : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
                    "og:type": "fitness.course",
                    "og:title": "My title",
                    "og:description": "The ride you took",
                    "fitness:duration:value": self.rideModel.totalSeconds,
                    "fitness:duration:units": "s",
                    "fitness:distance:value": self.rideModel.totalDistance,
                    "fitness:distance:units": "m",
                ];

                var i = 0;

                let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm'"




                for point in trackPointItems{


                    properties["fitness:metrics[\(i)]:location:latitude"] = point.latitude
                    properties["fitness:metrics[\(i)]:location:longitude"] = point.longitude
                    properties["fitness:metrics[\(i)]:location:altitude"] = point.altitude
                    properties["fitness:metrics[\(i)]:timestamp"] = formatter.stringFromDate(point.timeStamp)


                    i += 1;

                }

                let graphObject = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: properties)

                let action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()
                action.actionType = "fitness.course"
                action.setObject(graphObject, forKey: "fitness.course")

                let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()

                content.action = action
                content.previewPropertyName = "fitness.course"


                FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered I had too many points. I reduced the number of points in my array - only took every 2nd point. Then it worked.